# Connecting components to an arduino without a breadboard

Tags: arduino, wiring, pins

I've never worked with an arduino before, so bear with me.

I'm looking to start a project with an arduino nano, and I want to keep everything as small and as light as possible. Because of this, I want to avoid using a breadboard. Ideally I want to wire the arduino directly to the components. How would I go about doing this? For example, lets say I want to connect a PIR motion sensor to the nano. What kind of wire will connect the arduino pins to the holes in this component? Sorry if this is an obvious question. The images of the PIR components and the nano are below.

*edit: Also I'm hoping to avoid soldering just because I might want to re-use either of the components.*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use some [30awg](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/R30BLK-0100/K394-ND/221679) rework wire for something like that.  Get one or two colors. Then just strip cut and solder.

Comment: Oh I should have explained. Ideally I won't be soldering since I might want to reuse the arduino or the components. Is this possible?

Comment: Just because you solder to something doesn't make it non reusable, you can just unsolder a wire.   But maybe this is more your speed https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9140 solder the male ends to your components and now you'll have female plugs you can slide onto the audrino connectors.  Or solder a header to that PIR and get some female to female jumper wires.

Comment: Ah fantastic, that looks like what I'm after! If the PIR already has pins on it, like [this](http://i.imgur.com/EgRaeoL.gif), can I avoid soldering altogether?

Comment: And simply use female to female jumper wires?

Comment: Yes with female to female ones, spark fun has those to but my link was male to female

Comment: Wire wrap wire used with the wrapping tool will be more compact than socketed jumper cables - if you want to do a quick test, you can use those, while wire wrap though taking slightly longer is more compact and good for something you want to keep for a while.